# HTML parsing issue

Tags: html

I noticed in my element inspector (both chrome and firebug) that the html was parsed different from how i had intended it to be parsed.
Some elements ended up outside of their parent element, often this comes from broken html (unclosed tags etc.).
I threw the code in the W3C validator and narrowed the html down to just a few lines.

My HTML looks like:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>title because we must</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <div>test</div>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error i get is

> Line 10, Column 6: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.

Since the HTML5 validator is still experimental i figured i should try the XHTML 1.1 validator as well. It then mentions that I might be trying to put a block element within a inline element. This shouldn't be the case since both "p" and "div" are block elements by default.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: `p` is not allowed to contain block elements like `div`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element: “Content model: [Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1).”

Comment: don't forget to include a doctype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `p` element cannot contain a `div` element

The end tag of the `p` element is optional

Therefore:

```
<p>
    <div>test</div>
</p>
```

Means:

```
<p></p>
<div>test</div>
</p>
```

So you have an end tag for an element that is no longer open.

> Since the HTML5 validator is still experimental i figured i should try the XHTML 1.1 validator aswell. It then mentions that I might be trying to put a block element within a inline element.

Yes, in the extended explanation of the error it mentions that you **might** be trying to put a block element within a inline element.

The error message itself reads:

> document type does not allow element "div" here

which is quite clear.

Comment: In other words, you mean that the opening `<p>` is assumed by the parser to be closed as soon as it reaches the `div`. Then when the closing `</p>` is reached it does not match any known `<p>` that is still "open". Is this correct?

Comment: I was under the impression that a <p> was just a block element (like div) with other default values for the margin. Seems i was wrong, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Boaz — It isn't an assumption. The spec requires that elements with optional end tags are closed by the opening of an element which cannot be a child node of that element. It is just following the rules. But otherwise, yes.

Comment: @user6 — It is a block element, but it also has different rules for what child elements it can have.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place a `div` element inside a paragraph `<p>` tag.

This is invalid:

```
<p>
  <div>test</div>
</p>
```

The correct way would be to wrap the `div` around the `p`.

Answer (score -1):

we can not put `<div>` inside `<p>` ,as it is inline element and doing so is not recommended as per w3c standards,still if you do so browser will show that div out side p tag like this

```
<p></p>
<div>div contents<div>
<p></p>
```

for reference see following

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html

> `<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->`

Comment: You are misreading the DTD. That doesn't mean "this is an inline element" it means "this can contain inline elements". The HTML 4 specification is beside the point though, the question says "HTML 5".

Comment: The end tag for a paragraph that isn't open will be ignored by parsers, it won't generate a new, empty paragraph.